# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction operator does not exist: uuid = text

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using flask Sqlalchemy with a Postgres db and I'm trying to filter to find all the instances of a model where 1 string value of a json data column is equal to another (UUID4) column.

```
class MyModel (db.Model):
id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,
                   index=True, unique=True, nullable=False,
                   server_default=sa_text("uuid_generate_v4()"))
site = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey(
        'site.id'), index=True, nullable=False)
data = db.Column(JSON, default={}, nullable=False)
```

and these models' data column looks like

```
{
    "cluster": "198519a5-b04a-4371-b188-2b992c25d0ae",
    "status": "Pending"
}
```

This is what I'm trying:

`filteredModels = MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.site == MyModel.data['cluster'].astext)`

I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: uuid = text
LINE 4: ...sset.type = 'testplan' AND site_static_asset.site = (site_st...
                                                             

HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that Postgresql doesn't have a way to directly compare UUIDs with text values.  In other words, it cannot process

```py
MyModel.site == MyModel.data['cluster'].astext
```

To get around this, you need to [cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) one side of the comparison to be the same type as the other.  Either of these should work:

```py
from sqlalchemy import cast, String

MyModel.query.filter(cast(MyModel.site, String) == MyModel.data['cluster'].astext)

MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.site == cast(MyModel.data['cluster'].astext, UUID))
```